# is it possible to use Powershell 7 inside PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell

Just curious , is it possible to use Powershell 7  inside  PowerShell ISE ? Even though powershell 7 , I can't see 7 as version in the output of Get-Host commmand.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If you have Powershell Remoting enabled it might work by entering this in the ISE command line:

```
Enter-PSSession -ConfigurationName powershell.7 -ComputerName localhost
```

Then the script editor should have Powershell 7 Intellisense.

However this is a kludge, if it works. Use Visual Studio Code and the Powershell extensions. The ISE is dead in the water and won't be developed further IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Officially For PowerShell 6 core and later versions, Microsoft has said Visual Studio Code is a cross-platform editor, making it easier to write reliable PowerShell scripts.